# Subgroups of solvable Lie groups are closed

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was reading this [article](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lie_group,_solvable#References) about solvable Lie groups. I quote:

> "An arbitrary connected subgroup of a simply-connected solvable Lie group is closed and simply connected"

He refers this to a paper of  Mal'tsev, [On the theory of Lie groups in the large](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/870a0126bcf03c3379124866491651cd/sm6329.pdf)

I need a help to understand the idea of the proof. Thanks!

Comment: It's not true, even in $\mathbf{R}^2$ there are dense connected proper subgroups, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167100/how-do-the-subgroups-of-mathbb-c-which-are-connected-path-connected-in

Comment: @YCor Thanks! So what is the right statement should be: An arbitrary connected subgroup of a simply-connected solvable Lie group is $a \ Lie \ subgroup$ and simply connected

Comment: No, this is precisely what's false. The correct statement should be that an arbitrary connected immersed Lie subgroup of a simply connected solvable Lie group is closed and simply connected.

Comment: @YCor So what about the following statement, is it true? Every simply-connected solvable Lie group $R_0$ has a complexification $R$ such that $R_0$ is closed in $R$?

Comment: This is probably true, but is a distinct problem.

Comment: @YCor Do you have an idea or a reference for the proof? Thanks!